# Randomize database table result with LINQ

Tags: linq

```
from f in db.Table1
orderby Guid.NewGuid()
select f
```

this doesn't seem to work. how can i randomize results?

Answer (score 1):

How about

SELECT TOP 1 column FROM table ORDER BY NEWID and skip the linq :)

Or try this:

```
var t = (from row in db.Table1 order by table1.random()
         select row).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this works (not tested):

```
 (from f in db.Table1 select new { f, r = Guid.NewGuid()}).OrderBy(x => x.r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Randomize whole list

```
db.Table1.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
```

Get single Random

```
db.Table1.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to write an extension method for this.

```
IEnumerable<T> Randomize(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    T[] result = list.ToArray();
    Random random = new Random();

    for(int i = result.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        result[i] = random.Next(i);
    }

    return (result);
}
```